# In jQuery how do I do something after an event has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Use case: 
I have a table that users enter order lines into. The table is a list of products, they can page up and down in the table. If they've entered a quantity into one product and then page down they need to be focused on the input field in the same column they started from, but at the new row, the page down has moved to.

Problem:
The page down changes the hover location. So I can get which row has the hover state and change focus to the correct column in that row.  I need code to execute after the page down has completed and a new row has: hover.

But because page down is async, getting the row with the hover state in my event handler returns the current row, not the one that will have: hover when the page down completes. How do I write a page down event handler so that code is executed after the page down has completed?

Attaching a promise to the table with code that executes after the 'keydown' type event is complete doesn't work. It runs before the new row has: hover state.

Comment: Some code would be good here,all one can do is imagine what you want to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.activeElement` to get the element that has focus, get the column from that and set the focus using `$(columnSelector).focus()` to newly populated records column.

Another way is to have focus event handler and maintain the last focused column name in a variable.

Comment: Getting the focus is easy, the problem is setting the focus in the correct row after a page down event. I know which column in the table body needs to be focused after the page down. The problem is that working out which row the hover has moved to after the page down.